# Clear the text on click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to clear all the previous search term and the results ([here is what happens after the first search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duhti.png)). I was able to clear the search term, but not able to remove found n elements and the searched results when we click on any other alphabets ([here is what happens after the second search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJB71.png)).

In this example, when I searched for a letter A, it shows the results with found 27 words, then I clicked on letter B, it removed the searched word from the text but not the "found n elements" text.

Can anyone please help me on this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  // ===================================
  
  // Filter per data-key="value"
  $.fn.filterData = function(key, value) {
    return this.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data(key) == value;
    });
  };
  // :contains case-insensitive
  $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
      return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
  });
  // reset
    function resetAlphabet(ab, letter) {
    var starter = (letter == '') ? $(ab).children('button').first().data('value') : letter;
    var lettercode = starter.charCodeAt(0);    
    if ((lettercode >= 65) && (lettercode <= 90) && (ab != '')) {
      activateLetter($(ab).children('button').filterData("value", starter));
    }
  }
  // active div letter
  function activateLetter(ellet) {
    var thisletter = $(ellet).data('value');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $(ellet).addClass('active');
    $(ellet).siblings().removeClass('active');
    if (!$("#" + thisletter).hasClass('active')) {
      $(source).children('div').removeClass('active');
      $("#" + $(ellet).data('value')).addClass('active');
    }
  }
  // delay 
  function delay(callback, ms) {
    var timer = 0;
    return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        callback.apply(context, args);
      }, ms || 0);
    };
  }

  // Startup
    var $ts = $('.text-search');
    var source = '';
    var alphabet = '';
  var searchtitle = '';
  var searchin = '';
  var lbl = '';
    var $elemsfound;
  var offset = 0;
          
    if ($ts.length > 0) {       
        alphabet = $ts.data('alphabet') || alphabet;
        source = $ts.data('source') || source;
    searchtitle = $ts.data('searchtitle') || searchtitle;
    lbl = $("label[for='" + $ts.attr('id') + "']");
    offset = $ts.data('offset') || 0;
    offset = ((searchtitle != '') && offset == 0)  ? parseInt($(searchtitle).css('marginTop')) : offset;
    
        if ($(source).length == 1) {                         
      if (alphabet != '') {
        var $ab = $(alphabet);
        if ($ab.length > 0) {       
          var alphaletters = $(source).children('div');
          $(alphaletters).css('backgroundColor','').css('border','');
          $ab.html('');
          $(alphaletters).each(function(id, elem){
            $ab.append('<button type="button" data-value="' + $(elem).attr('id') + '">' + $(elem).attr('id') + '</button>' + " | ");
          });               
          $ab.on('click', 'button', function(e){            
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.text-search').val('');          
            activateLetter($(this))
          }); 
          resetAlphabet(alphabet, '');
        } else {
          alphabet = '';
          $(source).children('div').addClass('active');
        }
      } else {
        $(source).children('div').addClass('active');
      }
            
            $('body').on('keyup', '.text-search', delay(function(e){
                var sSearch = $(this).val();                
                if (sSearch != '') {                    
          var fl = sSearch.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
          $(searchin + '.found').removeClass('found');
          searchin = source + ((alphabet == '') ? '' : ' > div#' + fl) + ((searchtitle == '') ? '' : ' ' + searchtitle);
                    console.log('search for a word: "' + sSearch + '" in "' + searchin + '"');
                    $elemsfound = $(searchin + ':contains("' + sSearch + '")');
          console.log('element found: ' + $elemsfound.length);
          if ($elemsfound.length > 0) {
            resetAlphabet(alphabet, fl);            
            if (searchtitle != '') {
              var goto = $elemsfound.first().offset().top - offset;
              $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: goto}, 500 );
            } else {
              console.log('it is a global search')
              $(source).html().replace(sSearch, '<span class="found">' + sSearch + '</span>');
            }
          } else {
            searchin = source + ((alphabet == '') ? '' : ' > div') + ((searchtitle == '') ? '' : ' ' + searchtitle);
            console.log('I DID NOT FIND ANYTHING so I am looking for a word:"' + sSearch + '" in "' + searchin + '"');
            $elemsfound = $(searchin + ':contains("' + sSearch + '")');
            if ($elemsfound.length > 0) {              
              fl = $elemsfound.first().parent().attr('id');
              resetAlphabet(alphabet, fl);
              searchin = source + ((alphabet == '') ? '' : ' > div#' + fl) + ((searchtitle == '') ? '' : ' ' + searchtitle);
              $elemsfound = $(searchin + ':contains("' + sSearch + '")');
              var goto = $elemsfound.first().offset().top - offset;
              console.log(goto);
              $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: goto}, 500 );
            }
          }  
          $elemsfound.addClass('found');
          if (lbl.length == 1) {lbl.html('Found' + ($elemsfound.length == 1 ? '' : '') + ' ' + $elemsfound.length + ' word' + ($elemsfound.length == 1 ? '' : 's'))};
                } else {
          resetAlphabet(alphabet, '');
          $(searchin).removeClass('found');
          if (lbl.length == 1) {lbl.html('Browse the glossary using this index')}
        }
            }, 500));
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {font-family:helvetica;font-size:14px;}
label  {display:block;}
input[type='text'] 
{width:100%; font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px 8px;}
h3 {margin-top:30px;}

.alphabet {display:block; width: 1210px;}
.alphabet button {
  font: inherit;
  color: #398FFF;;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin: 0 -6px 10px -5px;
  border:none;
  background: none;
  padding:0;
  box-shadow:0;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline:0;
}
.alphabet:focus {outline:0;}
.alphabet button:hover {background-color:#FFF; font-weight:bold;} 
.alphabet button.active {background-color:#ffa505; font-weight:bold; color:#FFF; box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px #FFF inset; }

.glossary {display:block; width:100%; clear:both;}
.glossary .letter {display:none; width: 1115px;; clear:both; text-align:justify; padding-bottom:30px;}
.glossary .letter.active {display:block;}
.glossary h3 {font-size:18px; font-weight:300; margin-bottom:5px;}
.glossary h3.found {font-weight:bold;color: #800020;}
.glossary span.found {background-color:red;}

h3.gloss{
font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    }
h3.browse{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: 600;
    }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="sticky">
        <h3 class="gloss">Glossary</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms..." id="text-search" class="text-search" data-source="#glossary" data-alphabet="#alphabet" data-searchtitle="h3" data-offset="300"/>

        <h3 class="browse">Browse by alphabet</h3>
        <label for="text-search">Browse the glossary using this index</label>
        <div class="alphabet" id="alphabet">         
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="glossary" id="glossary">
                <div class="letter" id="A">
                <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr></div>


                <div class="letter" id="B">
                <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test<h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    
                    <hr>
                                </div>


</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call the same code as you use at the beginning (`lbl.html('Browse the glossary using this index')`. You can set it as a function (`resetMsg`), then call it from the `click` handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  // ===================================
  var $ts = $('.text-search');
    var source = '';
    var alphabet = '';
  var searchtitle = '';
  var searchin = '';
  var lbl = '';
    var $elemsfound;
  var offset = 0;
  // Filter per data-key="value"
  $.fn.filterData = function(key, value) {
    return this.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data(key) == value;
    });
  };
  // :contains case-insensitive
  $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
      return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
  });
  // reset
    function resetAlphabet(ab, letter) {
    var starter = (letter == '') ? $(ab).children('button').first().data('value') : letter;
    var lettercode = starter.charCodeAt(0);    
    if ((lettercode >= 65) && (lettercode <= 90) && (ab != '')) {
      activateLetter($(ab).children('button').filterData("value", starter));
    }
  }
  // active div letter
  function activateLetter(ellet) {
    var thisletter = $(ellet).data('value');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $(ellet).addClass('active');
    $(ellet).siblings().removeClass('active');
    if (!$("#" + thisletter).hasClass('active')) {
      $(source).children('div').removeClass('active');
      $("#" + $(ellet).data('value')).addClass('active');
    }
  }
  // delay 
  function delay(callback, ms) {
    var timer = 0;
    return function() {
      var context = this, args = arguments;
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function () {
        callback.apply(context, args);
      }, ms || 0);
    };
  }
  
  function resetMsg(){
    let lbl = $("label[for='" + $ts.attr('id') + "']");
    lbl.html('Browse the glossary using this index')
  }

  // Startup
    
  
          
    if ($ts.length > 0) {       
        alphabet = $ts.data('alphabet') || alphabet;
        source = $ts.data('source') || source;
    searchtitle = $ts.data('searchtitle') || searchtitle;
    lbl = $("label[for='" + $ts.attr('id') + "']");
    offset = $ts.data('offset') || 0;
    offset = ((searchtitle != '') && offset == 0)  ? parseInt($(searchtitle).css('marginTop')) : offset;
    
        if ($(source).length == 1) {                         
      if (alphabet != '') {
        var $ab = $(alphabet);
        if ($ab.length > 0) {       
          var alphaletters = $(source).children('div');
          $(alphaletters).css('backgroundColor','').css('border','');
          $ab.html('');
          $(alphaletters).each(function(id, elem){
            $ab.append('<button type="button" data-value="' + $(elem).attr('id') + '">' + $(elem).attr('id') + '</button>' + " | ");
          });               
          $ab.on('click', 'button', function(e){            
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.text-search').val('');          
            activateLetter($(this));
            resetMsg();
          }); 
          resetAlphabet(alphabet, '');
        } else {
          alphabet = '';
          $(source).children('div').addClass('active');
        }
      } else {
        $(source).children('div').addClass('active');
      }
            
            $('body').on('keyup', '.text-search', delay(function(e){
                var sSearch = $(this).val();                
                if (sSearch != '') {                    
          var fl = sSearch.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
          $(searchin + '.found').removeClass('found');
          searchin = source + ((alphabet == '') ? '' : ' > div#' + fl) + ((searchtitle == '') ? '' : ' ' + searchtitle);
                    console.log('search for a word: "' + sSearch + '" in "' + searchin + '"');
                    $elemsfound = $(searchin + ':contains("' + sSearch + '")');
          console.log('element found: ' + $elemsfound.length);
          if ($elemsfound.length > 0) {
            resetAlphabet(alphabet, fl);            
            if (searchtitle != '') {
              var goto = $elemsfound.first().offset().top - offset;
              $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: goto}, 500 );
            } else {
              console.log('it is a global search')
              $(source).html().replace(sSearch, '<span class="found">' + sSearch + '</span>');
            }
          } else {
            searchin = source + ((alphabet == '') ? '' : ' > div') + ((searchtitle == '') ? '' : ' ' + searchtitle);
            console.log('I DID NOT FIND ANYTHING so I am looking for a word:"' + sSearch + '" in "' + searchin + '"');
            $elemsfound = $(searchin + ':contains("' + sSearch + '")');
            if ($elemsfound.length > 0) {              
              fl = $elemsfound.first().parent().attr('id');
              resetAlphabet(alphabet, fl);
              searchin = source + ((alphabet == '') ? '' : ' > div#' + fl) + ((searchtitle == '') ? '' : ' ' + searchtitle);
              $elemsfound = $(searchin + ':contains("' + sSearch + '")');
              var goto = $elemsfound.first().offset().top - offset;
              console.log(goto);
              $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: goto}, 500 );
            }
          }  
          $elemsfound.addClass('found');
          if (lbl.length == 1) {lbl.html('Found' + ($elemsfound.length == 1 ? '' : '') + ' ' + $elemsfound.length + ' word' + ($elemsfound.length == 1 ? '' : 's'))};
                } else {
          resetAlphabet(alphabet, '');
          $(searchin).removeClass('found');
          if (lbl.length == 1) {resetMsg()}
        }
            }, 500));
        }
    }
});
```

```css
body {font-family:helvetica;font-size:14px;}
label  {display:block;}
input[type='text'] 
{width:100%; font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px 8px;}
h3 {margin-top:30px;}

.alphabet {display:block; width: 1210px;}
.alphabet button {
  font: inherit;
  color: #398FFF;;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  font-size:14px;
  margin: 0 -6px 10px -5px;
  border:none;
  background: none;
  padding:0;
  box-shadow:0;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  outline:0;
}
.alphabet:focus {outline:0;}
.alphabet button:hover {background-color:#FFF; font-weight:bold;} 
.alphabet button.active {background-color:#ffa505; font-weight:bold; color:#FFF; box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 2px #FFF inset; }

.glossary {display:block; width:100%; clear:both;}
.glossary .letter {display:none; width: 1115px;; clear:both; text-align:justify; padding-bottom:30px;}
.glossary .letter.active {display:block;}
.glossary h3 {font-size:18px; font-weight:300; margin-bottom:5px;}
.glossary h3.found {font-weight:bold;color: #800020;}
.glossary span.found {background-color:red;}

h3.gloss{
font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    }
h3.browse{
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: 600;
    }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="sticky">
        <h3 class="gloss">Glossary</h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter search terms..." id="text-search" class="text-search" data-source="#glossary" data-alphabet="#alphabet" data-searchtitle="h3" data-offset="300"/>

        <h3 class="browse">Browse by alphabet</h3>
        <label for="text-search">Browse the glossary using this index</label>
        <div class="alphabet" id="alphabet">         
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="glossary" id="glossary">
                <div class="letter" id="A">
                <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr>
                    <h3>A</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    <hr></div>


                <div class="letter" id="B">
                <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test<h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    <h3>B</h3></br>
                    Test
                    
                    
                    <hr>
                                </div>


</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering this issue and it indeed clears the found results label when we click on any other index but I want to clear the entire search result also, which is still showing as in maroon colour and bold when we come back to the index A.